# Loading composer package into Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to add the following [package](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) to my Laravel 5.2 project.  At the top of my class I have added

```
use PhpImap\Mailbox as ImapMailbox;
use PhpImap\IncomingMail;
use PhpImap\IncomingMailAttachment;
```

I then do something like this

```
$mailbox = new ImapMailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'some@gmail.com', '*********', __DIR__);
```

At the moment, when I visit the page I get

> Class 'PhpImap\Mailbox' not found

I have tried many different ways to load it with the same result.  Because this package is not Laravel specific, I don't know if I need to add anything else?  Normally when I add Laravel packages I create a provider and alias, do I need to do that here?

Any information appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify how you installed the package via composer?

Comment: I added the line to my composer.json file and then ran composer update.

Comment: I've just tried with this package. And it works fine

Comment: Can it be a permissions issue?